# Are golden tag badges broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-badges

Now I don't mean to complain, but I was curious if perhaps the feature was not working.

According to the [tag badge page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags) golden tag badges are awarded for 1000 upvotes in a given tag (not counting wikis).

According to the [[starcraft-2] tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/starcraft-2/topusers).  I've hit that number (actually I hit it over a week ago).

Now at first I thought, perhaps that number does not represent the correct number of upvotes, but I've been lead to believe [otherwise](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/new-tag-statistics/)

> The number next to the user names reflects the number of non-community wiki answer upvotes for each user. This is the same algorithm used to award [the tag-based badges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/specialist-badge-implemented/), so if you ever wondered how close you are to getting one of those badges, now you know!

Comment: I suspect since Sam reworked this, the quoted text is no longer true. Checking into it.

Comment: @Jeff this is a weird comment for me as my name is Sam... But I understand what you mean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The calculation has changed and is not documented anywhere in public that I know of.

There are three variables here for tag-based badges:

- minimum score
- minimum # of total questions in the tag
- minimum # of answers you have provided

(only non-cwiki posts count here)

right now for a gold badge that is

- 1000 score
- 100 questions total
- 0.2 * 1000 = 200 answers

Since the current result for you and [starcraft-2] is

- 1137 score
- 437 questions total
- 117 answers

the last one is why it's not being awarded.

We should probably have the /badges page document these minimum requirements as replacement variables in the sidebar. I think this was on our todo and it got forgotten.

Edit: this is complete; the tag-based badges page now properly documents these thresholds. Sorry about that.